# is there an equivalent to geom_ribbon in highcharter?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-highcharter

Using [highcharter](http://jkunst.com/highcharter/), is there a way to replicate [geom_ribbon](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_ribbon.html) form `ggplot2`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is called `arearange`. You can check the 3rd example in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/highcharter/vignettes/charting-data-frames.html.

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(data, "arearange", hcaes(x, low = lowvalue, high = highvalue))
```

[image]