# Cannot combine a Ribbon in highcharter (R) with normal line series

Tags: r, highcharts

I am trying to produce a ribbon on my highcharter chart (roughly following [is there an equivalent to geom_ribbon in highcharter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782623/is-there-an-equivalent-to-geom-ribbon-in-highcharter)).

However, the following example to produce a highcharter graph in `R` produces an error:

```
library(quantmod)
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)

getSymbols("VOD")
bb_data = BBands(Cl(VOD), n=20)

highchart(type = "stock") %>% 
  hc_add_series(bb_data, type = "arearange", hcaes(low = dn, high=up))
```

The error is:
`Error: 'hcaes(low = dn, high = up)' argument is not named in hc_add_series`

I have think this is because it is a time series object (xts).

It works if I cast it to a data.frame, but then I lose the date.

```
highchart(type = "stock") %>% 
  hc_add_series(as.data.frame(bb_data), type = "arearange", hcaes(low = dn, high=up))
```

I cannot combine it to with the moving average or price data as I would wish, as the ribbon is then missing from the subsequent plot:

```
highchart(type = "stock") %>% 
  hc_add_series(Cl(VOD), name = "VOD") %>% 
  hc_add_series(bb_data$mavg, name = "20d MA") %>% 
  hc_add_series(as.data.frame(bb_data), type = "arearange", hcaes(low = dn, high=up))
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I had to first extract the date from the time series object and bind it with the time series object to form a data frame or data table and then plot using that.

```
bb_data2 = cbind(date = as.Date(index(bb_data)), data.table(bb_data))

highchart(type = "stock") %>% 
  hc_add_series(bb_data2, type = "arearange", hcaes(x=date, low = dn, high=up)) %>%
  hc_add_series(Cl(VOD), name = "VOD") %>% 
  hc_add_series(bb_data$mavg, name = "20d MA")
```